# Minor Garage Rennovation - Drywall Questions

Tags: drywall, repair, painting

I am a new homeowner so I am pretty new to these tasks at hand but I recently moved into a newer build (2020) that has an attached garage with drywall already put up in it but that's about as far as it goes. It hasn't been painted or sanded so I am trying to get some help on figuring out what I all need to repair some of the images below (sorry for such beginner questions):

Issue 1 & 2)
[image]

As you can see, the paper part of the drywall is peeling and along the bottom there is a gap. This gap extends through the entire garage and there are a few places where the drywall paper is peeling like this. I'm not really interested in installing moulding so should I just fill it with silicone? What would you recommend?

Issue 3)
[image]

This drywall tape is visible all throughout the garage and I am not sure if I can just put primer over it and then paint without having visible lines.

Issue 4)
[image]

Where the garage frame meets the interior drywall there is a gap, similar to the floor. Would the same solution be used here too or should I do something else?

Thanks for all of your suggestions!

Comment: How pretty do you want the finished product to be?  Like an interior wall?  I recommend at least painting the walls, otherwise that finish tends to yellow over time.  (I wish the PO of my garage had painted the walls.)

Answer (score 1):

That will joint definately show through when painted.

It needs to be smoothed with sand paper and then more coats of joint compound and more sanding before painting.

Use a bright light close to the surface (at a tight angle) to highlight  ridges or hollows by causing shadows.

Paint doesn't stick to silicone caulk, if you want to paint it use acrylic latex caulk.

The  torn part can be patched by tearing off or glueing down the loose parts and then appyling joint compound and sanding etc, as for a joint.

Drywall joints aren't hard to do, they are just hard to do efficiently a beginner will take longer and use more product than a pro, but with perseverance they can still get a professional looking result.

Comment: When adding the extra coats, going inches beyond what they did is good.  Do not limit yourself to a small area.

Comment: Thanks! What size backing rod would you suggest for the gaps when they range anywhere from 3/4" to 1"?

Comment: backer rod should start out  be wider than the crack, for 1"  you might need stuff that's normally used to lag pipes.  The gaps are 1" wide? you'll spend a fortune on caulk, using a trim (baseboard etc) will probably save money and look better.

Comment: I was considering baseboard but wasn't sure if that would look weird in a garage, especially since there's like a lip of raised cement about 5" above the actual garage floor and the gap is above that.

Comment: You could do a 6" baseboard

Comment: I think I am going to go this route. Snag a 100' roll of vinyl and put that down.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is industry-standard "Level 2" drywall finish. It is the minimum required to achieve smoke/fire containment, and is almost invariably what you will find in residential garages. Additional work is obviously required if you want a more refined finish, but none of it is necessary or desired by most homeowners. I really can't see the point of any of your suggestions, it's still going to look like a semi-finished garage, but go for it if that's your heart's desire.

Comment: I just think it looks like an eyesore with all of the hard globs of compound and all the lines.

Comment: It's a good, low-stress place to pick up some drywall finishing skills, and painting it white will make the whole garage much brighter, easier to see things in. But if you like the dark nasty hole look, suit yourself.